# How to match on the start of a string?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I want to perform a match on the *start* of a string slice. My current approach is:

```rust
fn main() {
    let m = "true other stuff";
    if m.starts_with("true") { /* ... */ } 
    else if m.starts_with("false") { /* ... */ }
}
```

But this is more verbose than I like. Another approach is:

```rust
fn main() {
    match "true".as_bytes() {
        [b't', b'r', b'u', b'e', ..] => { /* ... */ },
        [b'f', b'a', b'l', b's', ,'e', ..] => { /* ... */ },
        _=> panic!("no")
    }
}
```

But I don't want to write out each pattern manually as a byte array. Is there a better approach here?

Comment: use a parsing crate like nom.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`starts_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.starts_with) method of str inside the match statement.

```rust
fn main() {
    match "true" {
        s if s.starts_with("true") => { /* ... */ },
        s if s.starts_with("false") => { /* ... */ },
        _ => panic!("no")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is definitely closer to what I had in mind

Comment: This is just transforming the OPs if statements into a match statement with if guards.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed do you have a better approach? If so, please tell.